# How to get rid of the %20 from my url when extracting a query from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, url, phpmyadmin

Ok I manually inserted the name New York in my database. Now I want to display as two words as New York and it works fine but when I want to turn into a link like newyork.mydomain.com the two words doesnt combine instead it does new%20york.mydomain.com.  Is there anyway to keep the name in two words in the database but have them combine when i turn into a link.  Keep in my when I do a query some names have one word and others have multiple words.  Here is the code I'm using.

```
while($state = mysql_fetch_array($states_set)) {
    echo "<td><a href=\"http://{$state["menu_name"]}.mydomain.com\">{$state["menu_name"]}</a></td>";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '', $city)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Having to get rid of `%20` might cause issue because the problem is how did it get there in the first place. You can use `urldecode` to decode any url

Example

```
$url = "new%20york.mydomain.com";
echo urldecode($url);
```

Output

```
new york.mydomain.com
```

Then use `str_replace` to replace empty space if necessary and `trim` during concatenation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm a beginner so and i just edited my code for you the see how im using it so how do i incorporate the $url as a query?  because im already using echo to echo out the query {$state["menu_name"]} im not using the newyork.mydomain.com.  im using it as {$state["menu_name"]}.mydomain.com

Comment: use `trim($state["menu_name"])` to remove any white space at beginning or at the end

Answer (score 0):

Hex 20 is space (20H or %20). Urls can't have spaces, so the best thing to do would be to delete all %20 or replace them with "_" or "-", with str_replace() or similar function.